# NSTableView Deselect a row

Tags: swift, nstableview

```
@IBAction func tableViewSelected(_ sender: NSTableView) {
    if(sender.selectedRow > -1 && sender.isRowSelected(sender.clickedRow)){
        tableView.deselectRow(sender.clickedRow);
    }
}
```

I am looking to deselect a row by clicking on the selected row.
However, this code is deselecting a row immediately once I click on a not selected row..

How can I do it?

Comment: Override `func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent)`.

Comment: @Willeke but then how do you determine which row you have clicked on?

Comment: Get the location of the event, convert to local coordinates and ask the table view. Or use Command click to deselect rows.